# Change part of an accepted Merge Request

Tags: git, gitlab

A week ago, I accepted a merge request (in gitlab, in case that is useful information) that contained some code that I was afraid was going to be an issue. I am a wiser man now, and know that it indeed is an issue - lesson learned.

Is there a way to change the relevant commit upstream? I would like to avoid pushing a fix just for this, and rebasing as long as that code is part of the history creates difficulties as well.

Edit: What I am trying right now is to just `commit --amend` the code out and force push when I am done. But a lot happened since then, and I'd like to not break upstream.

Comment: Sure, you can always change commits. The question is whether you *can* without causing extreme inconvenience and annoyance for anyone else who has pulled since the original commit.

Comment: I know who pulled, and I can tell them to pull again. This time at least, 'people' isn't the problem. Only my inability to use git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want to amend a commit on branch that is not yet merged, but just accepted in an MR on gitlab.

This is fine as long as you communicate what you will do / have done with the people involved. For the rest of the people needing to pull the branch all they have to do is a `git pull --rebase`.

Comment: The branch was merged into `dev` when I accepted the merge request.

Comment: It's not recommended to amend commits on the dev-branch. This will cause many issues with everybody else which has to pull the branch later and will also destroy the merge-commit, which is a usefull information.

Comment: Fair enough. What is recommended in such a case then? Just a fix on top and deal with more difficult rebasing for a while?

Comment: Just branch of dev and patch the fix in a new Commit then go through the regular Merge request flow. This is the cleanest work flow that will not cause any issues.